setting cache control for static files nuxt3
I have some static files in the public folder e.g.

image.png
/favicons/favicon.ico
/img/myimage.jpg

and i want to add a cache control to every .png, .jpg, .ico
I dont want to add every single while to the route rules, so I thought something like this should work:
routeRules: {
  '**/*.jpg': { headers: { 'cache-control': `public,max-age=300,s-maxage=300` } },
},

But it doesn't work. Is there a pattern where I can match every filetype in every directory for that?
Thx!
